# Building Patio - Pavers against siding solution?

Tags: patio, siding, pavers

I used crushed gravel as a base for patio. I'd like the patio to get as close as possible to the house but am realizing that it may not be good to put the pavers right up against the siding.

The gravel is about now 3-4 inches "up" the siding as you can see in pictures.

Should I dig out the stones I put down against the house? Maybe just keep the patio 1/2 foot away from the house?

Ideas?[image]

Comment: What's under the siding? You might be able to remove the lower bit of siding.

Comment: @Tester101 Under the siding is the wall studs. It is a 80 year old house. The back 6 feet of the house is crawlspace... no basement underneath it.

Comment: The wood framed wall is below grade? Usually; even with a crawlspace, there's a foundation that comes up above grade level.

Comment: If I strip away the 3 inches of crushed gravel I put down there is a stone foundation. The siding runs down behind the stone foundation. If you look at the siding from the inside (in the crawlspace) it comes down to about 3 inches off bare dirt. The "foundation" really doesn't go above grade level. I was thinking about pulling back the gravel and pouring concrete on top of the foundation to raise it up a foot and then do vinyl siding on top of the wood siding?

Comment: If your wood framed wall is below grade, you're asking for rot, termites, and mold.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up digging out the stones for about a foot away from siding.

I poured a concrete "curb", making the curb form out of 1x6x8's in front of the siding about 8 inches above the ground and extending 18 inches into the ground.

Then I laid the pavers on top of the crush and run base, with sand on top to make everything level. Looks great. Laying your pavers up against the siding looks bad. Worked great.

Also in the picture above you can't see the new sideing. I just left the old siding on. After I poured the curb and laid the pavers I put some new siding on (right over top of the old) the siding goes right down to an inch above the curb. Perfect.